# Glob pattern for different file types in different directories

Tags: phpstorm, glob, prettier

I want to configure my IDE (PhpStorm) to run Prettier on save, for different file types in different directories, but it only accepts one glob pattern.

I want one pattern that will do the work of both of these patterns:

- `assets/**/*.{js,ts,json,css,scss,sass}`
- `**/*.{md,yml}`

I want to reformat `js,ts,json,css,scss,sass` files only within the `assets/` dir, and `md,yml` files anywhere they're found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this currently, please vote for [WEB-52968](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-52968/Switch-Prettier-from-using-glob-to-Scope) to get notified on any progress with this request

Comment: Thank you for the information. Scope would be superior. I upvoted your issue.